# Delete Orphan Snapshots that are older - Script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, snapshot

I have the following script to delete the snapshots that are 12 months old. But this deletes all snapshots that are older than 12 months. I have to identify the Orphan Snapshots that are 12 months and delete only the Orphan snapshots and not AMI Snapshots.

This Script deletes all snapshots that are 12 months old.

1. I want to identify and delete the orphan snapshots that are 12 months old, but this script deletes all snapshots older than 12 months.

```html
import boto 
import datetime
import dateutil
from dateutil import parser
from boto import ec2
 
connection=ec2.connect_to_region("REGION-NAME")
 
ebsAllSnapshots=connection.get_all_snapshots(owner='16-DIGIT-AWS-ACCOUNT-NUMBER')
 
#Get the 30 days old date
timeLimit=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)  
 
for snapshot in ebsAllSnapshots:
     
    if parser.parse(snapshot.start_time).date() <= timeLimit.date():
        print " Deleting Snapshot %s  %s "  %(snapshot.id,snapshot.tags)
        connection.delete_snapshot(snapshot.id) 
    else:
        # this section will have all snapshots which is created before 30 days
        print "Only Deleting Snapshots which is 365 days old"
```

Comment: You keep referring to "this script", but I see no script here.

Comment: @John Gordon, please check now. Thanks

Comment: How does one distinguish between an "AMI screenshot" and an "Orphan screenshot"?

Comment: @John, AMI Snapshots will have the ami ID in the description if the snapshot.